# GIT Server install failing on Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, gitolite

I'm trying to install my own git server with these instructions.

http://cisight.com/how-to-setup-git-server-using-gitolite-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric/

But I am get stuck at this point.

```
git clone --verbose  gitolite@ec2-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:testing.git
Cloning into 'testing'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

And I think it has something to do with this:

```
gitolite@ip-xxxx:~$ gl-setup tmp/john.pub 

key_read: uudecode Aklkdfgkldkgldkgldkgfdlkgldkgdlfkgldkgldkgdlkgkfdnknbkdnbkdnbkdnbkfnbkdfnbkdnfbkdfnbdknbkdnbkfnbkdbnkdbnkdfnbkd john@example.com
 failed
fprint failed
```

I always get the fail and I think its preventing me from cloning repo.The repo is there along with gitolite-admin.git repo. The permissions are this:

```
drwxr-x--- 8 gitolite gitolite 4096 Jun  6 16:29 gitolite-admin.git
drwxr-x--- 7 gitolite gitolite 4096 Jun  6 16:29 testing.git
```

So my question is what am I missing here?

Comment: Any chance you can do this installation with Gitolite V3 instead of the old Gitolite V2? I mean, don't apt-get gitolite... just clone it: git clone https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](http://matthewbass.com/2008/05/21/key_readuudecode-failed-when-pulling-from-git/) reports:

> acting on a hunch I removed the IP address of my git repo from my known hosts. The error immediately went away.
>
> If you’re getting the same message, determine the IP address or domain name of your git repo.
> Search for those values in your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file and remove them. You should be good to go after that.

It can be that, or you don't have generated your ssh key properly somehow.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f "${HOME}/.ssh/gitoliteadm" -C "Gitolite Admin access (not interactive)" -q -P ""
```

Comment: Yes, for some reason whenever I generate a key on my mac, the key generation process does not return a proper key. Works fine on another computer. So I need to do something about key generation on my mac.