# Gitlab CE Doesn't Add a Public Key to authorized_keys

Tags: linux, git, ssh, centos, gitlab

I just installed the newest Omnibus Gitlab in CentOS 7. I have added my public key to my account but gitlab keeps prompting me for a password every time I try to connect using ssh, like `ssh git@mygitlab.com`. The git home folder is `/var/opt/gitlab`.

Here are the various things that I've done:

- I have checked that write to authorized_keys is checked in the admin area -> settings -> network
- I have chmod the relevant folders and `authorized_keys` file. `0700` for home, `0711` for `.ssh` and `0600` for `authorized_key` file
- I have deleted and re-created the `authorized_keys` file
- I have checked various gitlab log files and nothing shows any clue
- I have restarted and reconfigured using `gitlab-ctl` and restarted the computer

Comment: What gives `ssh -Tv git@mygitlab`?

Comment: @phd

https://pastebin.com/EFLFZNkB

Comment: @phd, I have the private key, I can ssh to the same machine using other user name, I think the problem is the authorized_keys file in the server is not updated after I add the public key with gitlab web interface. I just added the public key manually, I can shh using git name, but there's no welcoming message and when I tried to clone, it gave me other error:

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: the repo name is correct, I copied pasted it from the gitlab project

Comment: Repo name doesn't matter, the problem is in ssh tunnel, that is, git is not yet involved.

Comment: I have solved half of the problem although I don't know what  the root cause is. I looked into this page https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/raketasks/maintenance.html#rebuild-authorized_keys-file about rebuilding authorized_keys, and gitlab rebuild the key and created authorized_keys.lock in the .ssh folder. Now, I can ssh -T git@mygitlab.com, although now I'm facing another problem. When I try to clone or push, gitlab said the project can't be found. :( . I guess I'll have to look for it more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to configure [Fast lookup of authorized SSH keys in the database](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/operations/fast_ssh_key_lookup.html).

This should solve the problem you're facing and it won't require manual rebuild of authorized_keys file whenever someone adds or removes SSH/deploy key in GitLab.

Edit: This bug was introduced with GitLab 12.9. It was [confirmed](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/212178) and it should be resolved with 12.9.1 patch release, which is expected to be released soon.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved half of the problem although I don't know what the root cause was. I looked into this page docs.https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/raketasks/maintenance.html#rebuild-authorized_keys-fileabout rebuilding authorized_keys using this command: `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:shell:setup`, and gitlab rebuild the key and created authorized_keys.lock in the .ssh folder. Now, I can ssh -T git@mygitlab.com, although the user name was changed to Anonymous, now I'm facing another problem. When I try to clone or push, gitlab said the project can't be found. :( . I guess I'll have to look for it more.

EDIT: somehow by luck, I managed to solve this by creating a new user, added the ssh key for that user and run `gitlab-rake gitlab:shell:setup` again to make Gitlab added the public key to authorized_keys file.

What a mess in Gitlab and I see ton of issues regarding this authorized_keys and ssh from a long long time ago (5 - 6 years ago and still similar issue) and it still happens now.